# how keep url in memory on click?

Tags: php

The idea of the code i want to make is the following.

On a page containing different url i want to keep in a var every url that would be clicked.

Let's say on my linkspage.html file i have

```
Text.... <br> ... <a href="http://..com/01.html">Link1</a>
<p>Text....<p> <br> ... <a href="http://..com/02.html">Link2</a>
<br> Text.... <br> ... <a href="http://..com/03.html">Link3</a>
```

Then i would like to find how to memorise Link3'url ON CLICK.

Store the adress in $urlvar .

In 01.html 02.html 03.html have a printf $urlvar that would show in my body content `http://..com/0x.html`

Hope you understood what i meant..
Thank u!

Comment: Checkout sessions ? Also I hope you aren't using php in `.html` pages ...

Comment: i'm not i used .html for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Just store it in a hidden field

you have to update when you are clicking on the link1,2&3 on Onclick.

Answer (score 0):

**Capture clicks with jQuery** and each click **create a tiny image in JS with arguments like ?url=blah**. **When it's loaded remove it** from the DOM tree. In the background, the IMG needs to be generated by a PHP file, [**1x1 transparent pixel**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203354/php-script-to-render-a-single-transparent-pixel-png-or-gif) and after you output the image you log whatever you need in your database.

*It's how analytics tools work.*

Comment: Thank you, seems a interesting solution. I just can't find solution on the internet on Capture click with jquery. Do you have some information links?

Comment: $('a').click(function(){ /* do stuff */ });

Comment: this just tell all the links to react when clicked. the url=blah is a bit fast thinked. the problem i have is to set blah as the active clicked link by the user.

Comment: @dansayag I'm gonna prescribe you PHP/jQuery books. They're good to read and LEARN. Whatever I say here will make no sense to you, so I'll just stop.